# How do I change link color in default, active and hover states globally for Tailwindcss?

Tags: tailwind-css

By default link color is blue. How do I override it globally in Tailwindcss so that I don't have to set `text-color-xxx` on every link throughout the app?

Answer (score 18):

You need to define base styles on global css file.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  a {
    @apply text-blue-900;
  }
}
```